# Add a column with product category ID in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: screenshot dashboard]

In Product Category admin page of Woocommerce, I'd like to have an extra column showing the Product Category IDs instead of manually find out on every product category's url.

I've found some snippet for showing the IDs in normal Wordpress categories but nothing about Woocommerce's product category.

Answer (score 2):

```
function add_post_tag_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['id'] = 'Id';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_columns', 'add_post_tag_columns' );

function add_post_tag_column_content( $content, $column, $id ) {
    if ( 'id' === $column ) {
        $content = $id;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'manage_product_cat_custom_column', 'add_post_tag_column_content', 10, 3 );
```

The hook `manage_edit-product_cat_columns` is used to modify/add new column heading.
The hook `manage_product_cat_custom_column` is used to display custom content of a specific column. Here we conditionally check the column heading is equal to `id` if so we assign `$id` third parameter value which holds the id of the category to the first parameter `$content`.

[image: Product category table with ID]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You were very exhaustive and above all thanks to your explanation you made me understand better what I was doing, and not a simple copy and paste.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @FrancescoRotondo Glad that your issue was resolved